# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmath' when running a Mac OS App compiled by PyInstaller : Problem with PyTesseract

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile my Python 3.9 script with PyInstaller on my MAC OS Catalina:
MAC OS CATALINA 10.15.6
Python 3.9
Pyinstaller 4.2

When I run my python script from the terminal on my Mac, it runs fine without any issues.

I compiled with this command:

```
sudo python3 -m PyInstaller --uac-admin --windowed --icon=MyScript_icon.icns MyScript.spec
```

here is MyScript.spec:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['MyScript.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/alisa/Dropbox/cff/Python/MyScriptFolder'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[( 'necessary_files/create_db.sql', '.'),
                    ( 'necessary_files/fra.traineddata', '.'),
                    ( 'ui.json', '.'),
                    ( 'MyScript_Install.sh', '.'),
                    ( 'necessary_files/assets', '.'),
                    ( 'necessary_files/selenium', '.'),
                    ( 'Start_MyScript.sh', '.'),
                    ( 'ui', 'ui' )],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['FixTk', 'tcl', 'tk', '_tkinter', 'tkinter', 'Tkinter'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='MyScript',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False , uac_admin=True, icon='myscript_icon.icns')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='MyScript')
app = BUNDLE(coll,
             name='MyScript.app',
             icon='MyScript_icon.icns',
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

When I double click on app, it doesn't launch the app. So I open it by command line:

```
open dist/MyScript.app/Contents/MacOS/MyScript
```

A Terminal windows is showing up and a few seconds later this error message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyScript.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "prepare_envir_appium.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "mymodules.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "pytesseract/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "pandas/__init__.py", line 179, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "pandas/testing.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "pandas/_testing.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/testing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.testing
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmath'
[21640] Failed to execute script MyScript
```

So I search for installing cmath but I can't.
So I added it as hidden import in spec file but it didn't work.

This line 46 in mymodules.py is the importation of Tesseract Python module:

```
import pytesseract
```

So I tried to reproduce this issue with this minimal code:

```
import pytesseract

print("Hello")
```

and I get exact same issue!!! So there is a problem with PyInstaller compiling pytesseract?

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5641#issuecomment-800476801) in the GitHub issues (looks like it's your post). I also had the same issue and solved for me simply add `--hiddenimport cmath` to your pyinstaller command

Comment: THank you for your help. I will try this asap.